# Static linking to libcrypto++, with g++

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libcrypto

I am trying to compile a program on my system with Debian Wheezy and g++4.7. I want it to be able to run on another system with Debian Squeeze (and no recent g++). I can't compile the program on the Squeeze, because I use certain `C++11` features the old g++ does not support, as well as a new Boost version and libcrypto++9.

As far as I understand the usual way to get around this problem is to static link the libraries not supported at the other system, in my case `libstdc`, `boost` and `crypto++`.

My (linking) compiler call right now is

```
g++-4.7 .obj/btcmirco.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lcrypto++ -Wl,-Bdynamic -lcurl -static-libgcc -std=c++11 -o MyProgram
```

However I seem to have missed something, because it throws a lot of undefined reference errors. It works fine if I dynamic link to `crypto++` (and only static link `libstdc` and `boost`).

Can anyone tell me whats wrong, or if there is a fundamental error in my approach?

The linker errors I get are (shorted):

```
`.text._ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD1Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libcrypto++.a(cryptlib.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libcrypto++.a(cryptlib.o)
`.text._ZN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeD2Ev' referenced in section `.text._ZN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeD1Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeD1Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libcrypto++.a(cryptlib.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP25MessageAuthenticationCodeD5Ev]' of /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libcrypto++.a(cryptlib.o)
```

Comment: I've filed #708370 about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and this has to do with the fact that you are trying to mix code generated by g++-4.7 (your program) with code generated by a previous version of g++ (cryptopp library).

The reason behind this is that when you execute compile the library executing `make` command, it uses the default version of `g++` set up for your system, usually the one that comes with the OS.

In order to solve the issue what you should do is compile `cryptopp` library with `g++-4.7`.
For that, compile the library by executing `make CXX=g++-4.7`. The resulting static library shouldn't give you the error when being linked with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't tested but I guess it will work if you had the same problem. But why does the problem inly appear if I do a static link and not if I use a dynamic link? Shouldn't this cause the same errors (either at compile- or runtime)?